# Does Sitecore encrypt the information it captures from forms in the new Sitecore Forms?

Tags: sitecore-forms

Out-of-the-box, Sitecore does not encrypt the information it captures from forms in the **Web Forms for Marketers** database. It was a known issue and you could find nice blog posts on how to implement encryption in the **Web Forms for Marketers** information such as http://josedbaez.com/2016/09/wffm-encryption/ and https://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/06/21/encrypt-web-forms-for-marketers-fields-in-sitecore.

Was that solved in the new **Sitecore Forms**? I couldn't find any information in the Sitecore documentation mentioning that.

### Update

To whom it may concern. I've managed to encrypt the data and enable the encryption at rest which I share here https://restlesscode.wordpress.com/2018/01/21/make-sitecore-forms-more-secure/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, no it does not.  I created a simple form, added the `Save Data` save action and checked the database.  It was not encrypted.

[image]

I'm off to dig a little deeper to find if this is a setting you can configure!

Comment: It would be nice if you could set this up without needing to add custom code, but I am afraid, in this first release it is not available.

Comment: It looks that way.  Just decompiled the save action and looked at the Sql DataProvider - no encryption being done in code.  And no settings in the `Sitecore.Experience.Forms*.config` files.

Comment: @JoãoNeto, you should use UserVoice and request that as a future feature.

Comment: @DylanYoung I already submitted it as a user voice request. :)

Comment: I thought encryption was part of GDPR requirements (or not?) and sitecore 9 is advertised as compliant. What am I missing here

Comment: It doesn't seem to be yet. I made a blog post comparing WFFM with Forms. And it seems Forms is very basic and is missing a lot of nice features found in WFFM.

Comment: @josedbaez they are advertising “xDB” as being GDPR-compliant now. All of that data is encrypted at rest. The forms database is not yet.